# ajaxform: how to remove it, so default submit action is taken

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

how can I remove an ajaxForm from the form element so the default action is taken?

`$('form').off('ajaxForm')`

or

`$('form').unbind('ajaxForm')`

do not work

initialization was `$('form').ajaxForm({...});`

Comment: which plugin are you using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using the `ajaxFormUnbind`, method provided by the plugin

```
$('form').ajaxFormUnbind()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LQAwm/)

Comment: It unbinds the events added by the ajaxForm Plugin. Here's the code -> https://github.com/malsup/form/blob/3.51/jquery.form.js#L927