# jquery.form.js - how can I unbind this form

Tags: jquery

I'm using the form uploader plugin at this site to upload photos http://jquery.malsup.com/

It works really well and I'm happy with it.

The only catch is I when I remove the HTML DIV when the form is attached (clear the HTML including Form element) & then re-create it (I need to do this for the site) on the second re-creation of the HTML the form attaches for a second time. (eg: it doesn't unbind when the element is removed).

I've been trying to unbind the event but I can't seem to do it.

The inital bind looks like this

```
$('#joinPhotoUploadFormProfile').ajaxForm({
```

http://jquery.malsup.com/ - the site options for the plugin doesn't show an unbind.

I've tried things like:

```
$('#joinPhotoUploadFormProfile').children().off();
$('#joinPhotoUploadFormProfile').add("*").off();
$('#joinPhotoUploadFormProfile').ajaxFormUnbind();
$('#joinPhotoUploadFormProfile').unbind('ajaxForm');
```

any suggestions?

Below is how I set it up:

```
$('#joinPhotoUploadFormProfile').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
    $('#progressGallery').fadeIn('fast');
    var percentVal = '0%';
    $('#uploadGalleryBar').width(percentVal);
    $('#uploadGalleryPercentage').html(percentVal);
    },

    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
    $('#uploadGalleryBar').width(percentVal);
    $('#uploadGalleryPercentage').html(percentVal).css({'left':'40%','color':'lightblue'});
    },

    complete: function(xhr) {
```

Do I need to turn off delegation? how do I do this?

Comment: above is how I setup the ajaxForm call... I'm not sure how to set delegation... thx for your help..

Comment: The code shows a "delegation" option. If set, the handlers are not bound to the node itself, but to `document` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this:

[ajaxform: how to remove it, so default submit action is taken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098686/ajaxform-how-to-remove-it-so-default-submit-action-is-taken)

```
$('#joinPhotoUploadFormProfile').ajaxFormUnbind();
```

Should work.

**Just make sure that you call unbind before you remove the form!**