# CallBack Function Needed - .ajaxFormUnbind()

Tags: jquery, callback

I have the following code that works fine but is written poorly because of the setTimeout() used.

I need the 2 .ajaxFormUnbind() functions to finish before the other code runs. Without a delay or callback the .remove() happens before the .ajaxFormUnbind() complete.

```
    $('#joinPhotoUploadFormProfile').ajaxFormUnbind();
    $('#joinPhotoUploadFormGallery').ajaxFormUnbind();


    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#profileEditPrimaryPhotoManagementGifIMG').hide();
        hidePopUp('profile_photo_management');
        $('#profile_photo_management').remove();
    }, 10000);
```

I tried this but it doesn't fire:

```
$('#joinPhotoUploadFormProfile').ajaxFormUnbind(function() {
            $('#profileEditPrimaryPhotoManagementGifIMG').hide();
            hidePopUp('profile_photo_management');
            $('#profile_photo_management').remove();
});
```

Is there a way to get a callback to work for .ajaxFormUnbind()? When I tried the above it didn't enter the function - put in alert() to see code progress and didn't enter.

any ideas? thankyou

---

Function Comes from here: [jquery.form.js - how can I unbind this form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19831059/jquery-jquery-form-js-how-can-i-unbind-this-form)

Comment: Where does `ajaxFormUnbind` function comes from? Can't see it in jQuery's manual.

Comment: Comes from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19831059/jquery-jquery-form-js-how-can-i-unbind-this-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plugin (which is kinda old to be honest) doesn't use a callback in the function you want to use :

```
// ajaxFormUnbind unbinds the event handlers that were bound by ajaxForm
$.fn.ajaxFormUnbind = function() {
    return this.unbind('submit.form-plugin click.form-plugin');
};
```

Anyway, you can modify it simply like this :

```
// ajaxFormUnbind unbinds the event handlers that were bound by ajaxForm
$.fn.ajaxFormUnbind = function(callback) {
    callback = callback || function(){};
    return this.unbind('submit.form-plugin click.form-plugin', callback);
};
```

And use it like you tried in your 2nd code.

Comment: 2 questions - would I update the plugin with the code or can I just add to my js script (adding to mine is preferred)? What is a newer preferred plugin to use & why better? thx so much

Comment: If you want to stick with that plugin and want to use a callback function, then yes, update the plugin with that and give it a try. I'm not into jQuery plugin this time so I don't know if there's a better/newer/faster plugin now. Still, yours uses `.unbind()` from jQuery which is deprecated since 1.7.